# Llamar desde el controlador datos de columnas relacionadas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Buenos días compañeros, tengo relacionadas la tabla estudiantes y la tabla profesor en `SQL SERVER 2014` ahora estoy pasando a `ASP.NET MVC` la base de datos con `Entity Framework`. Ya generé los controladores y las vistas y quiero que desde mi vista profesor se pueda poner un `@Html.ActionLink` que me lleve a una vista donde se muestre la tabla estudiantes, pero no se que datos tienen que ir en el controlador para mandar llamar a esa vista.

```
public class ProfesorController : Controller
    {
        private EscuelaBDEntities db = new EscuelaBDEntities();

        // GET: Profesor
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var Profesor = db.Profesor.Include(p => p.Estudiante).Include(p => p.Salones).Include(p => p.Instituto);
            return View(Profesor.ToList());
        }

@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Profesor>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
```

Comment: En principio, debes tener una vista estudiantes asi como un controlador estudiantes, este controlador debe tener una accion que consulte la tabla de estudiantes y que reciba como parametro el id del profesor, es en este momento cuando obtienes la lista de estudiantes y la envias a tu vista de estudiantes tal cual estas haciendo actualmente con la vista de profesores.

Comment: Tengo mi controlador estudiante con su index o su vista con todos los estudiantes, y mi controlador profesor igual con su index, entiendo que lo que me dices es que en el controlador estudiante debo tener algo parecido a esto  public ActionResult Estudiantes(int id)
        {
            var Estudiante = db.Profesor.Include(p => p.Estudiante).Include(p => p.Salones).Include(p => p.Instituto);
            return View(Estudiante.ToList());
        } Como desde la vista del profesor llamo a este action que esta en otro controlador diferente

Comment: En el controlador de Estudiantes deberias tener algo asi como :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La accion de index de estudiante debe filtrar los estudiantes por el id de profesor que enviaste asi :

```
public ActionResult Index(int id) 
{ 
var Estudiante = db.Estudiante.Where(d => e.IdProfesor==id).Include(p => 
p.Salones).Include(p => p.Instituto); 
return View(Estudiante.ToList()); 
}
```

Esta accion yo la colocaria en un controlador estudiante y desde la vista de profesor la invocaria en cada linea de profesor algo asi como :

```
@Html.ActionLink(
"Ver Estudiantes",                                // linkText
"Index",                                          // actionName
"Estudiante",                                     // controllerName
new {                                             // routeValues
    id = Model.ProfesorId
    },
null                                              // htmlAttributes
```

)

Comment: Compañero esa parte la entiendo gracias no le entendia bien pero para mandar a llamar ese ActionResult desde de mi vista principal de Profesor es igual aunque sea de otro controlador o ese ActionResult  va en el controlador profesor?